# problems with win 8

Tags: boot, uefi

I have a HP compaq CQ58, with Win 8 preinstalled. I want to install Ubuntu on a different partition, and I have tried both with Ubuntu 10.12 and with Linux Secure Remix, I have disabled Secure Boot on the computer and made it bootable from cd, but it always says 'booting device failed, no volume label'. What did I get wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible dupliacate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Means your computer is unable to read the cd rom... are you sure you burned the cd/dvd right? did you burn is as an ".iso" ?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 recently to dual boot with Win 7 on a new partition. I got errors when trying to install while booting from the disc also so instead of installing it from the disc, I made a new folder & added wubi along with the installation ISO to it. After that I clicked on wubi & it installed perfectly from the ISO file.